# PHP Warning: require(...): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, directory, path, require

I´m working on a onlineshop.

I need to require the "nav_bar.php" file into the "item_page.php" file.

Here´s my directory:

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3mhj.png)

And here´s my code:

```
require "../nav_bar/nav_bar.php";
```

***note: I also tried a lot of other "path" variations but it never worked.***

Some examples of my tries:

```
require "source\main\nav_bar\nav_bar.php";

require "C:\Users\holli\OneDrive\Dokumente\onlineshop\source\main\nav_bar\nav_bar.php";
```

A few days ago, I got this Error. I already searched a ton of other questions and a lot of other websites with this error, but I can not find a answer for my problem...

I know, that this error is somehow common but I don´t know how I can solve this one.

Can anyone help me?

Here´s the error message:

```
error: Command failed: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "c:\Users\holli\OneDrive\Dokumente\onlineshop\source\main\item_page\item_page.php" PHP Warning:  require(../nav_bar/nav_bar.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\holli\OneDrive\Dokumente\onlineshop\source\main\item_page\item_page.php on line 8 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '../nav_bar/nav_bar.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\holli\OneDrive\Dokumente\onlineshop\source\main\item_page\item_page.php:8 Stack trace:
#0 {main}   thrown in C:\Users\holli\OneDrive\Dokumente\onlineshop\source\main\item_page\item_page.php on line 8
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7J4c.png)

***note: I use a VS-Code extension named: "five server"***

But I don´t think, this extension has something to do with the error.

Heres the extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your `include_path` as shown in the error doesn't include `.`, the current directory. Make sure to add the current directory to the include_path.  You can also use an absolute path like so: `require dirname(__DIR__)."/nav_bar/nav_bar.php";`

Comment: OK I will try the dirname Methode... Thank you hopefully IT works

Comment: Best way to include a file in php is by using `include("../nav_bar/nav_bar.php");`

Comment: What does `$fileLocation = dirname(__DIR__) . '/nav_bar/nav_bar.php';`
`echo 'The file ' . $fileLocation . ' '  . file_exists($fileLocation ) ? ' exists' : ' does not exist';exit;` output? As far as a fix, you can also try: `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '.');` before your require which uses `..`

Comment: @stillKonfuzed I would disagree with your claim involving `..` being the "best" way to include files. Generally the best solutions I've seen involve  `__DIR__` (or at least `__FILE__`) and dirname for moving up a directory or a variable like `$app_dir` or similar which get set through the script entry point, or a helper function like app_dir(). These could have easily been public_dir, public_path or similar based on a framework etc. But generally solutions which rely on `.` or `..` are less reliable since you're relying on the incude_path having a sane value and the current working directory.

Comment: It might also be helpful to get the output of the current working directory from the file you're working on: `echo getcwd();` note the current working directory changes based on the entry script, and [chdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir) can also tamper with it, etc. This info would be valuable if you're set on using `..` for moving up a directory.

Comment: Hello helloworld, please make sure that you the file has the appropriate permission in order for php to be able to open this file's stream. For Debian or CentOS it is recommended to set permission to `666` meaning that `read` and `write` is enabled for everyone. *Note*: make sure to set permissions to 555 after you finished troubleshooting the files, just for security reasons.

Comment: @kevin-y I was not pointing to use `..` but I was recommending to use `include` instead of `require`. For getting the exact path `__DIR__` is the best approach.

Comment: thank you all for your answers... I will try everyone of your Ideas and let you know, if something worked for me :)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve that error

Comment: Hello guys, I managed to solve it with your help... I will add a answer myself and thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `include_path` does not include the current directory...

Heres a example to solve this, with an absolute path:

```
require dirname(__DIR__)."/nav_bar/nav_bar.php";
```

Thanks `@Kevin Y` for the comment that solved that question